# Why does commutativity imply a certain expression with exponents?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $a, b$ in a group. If $ord(a) = n, ord(b) = m$, then $ab^{nm} = a^{nm}b^{nm} = e$ granted $ab = ba.$

I think $ab^{nm} = a^{nm}b^{nm} = e^mb^{nm} = b^{mn} = e^n = e.$ What does $ab = ba$ have to do with it? Do we need it to be able to say $b^{nm} = b^{mn}?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ don't commute, it's false that $(ab)^k=a^k b^k$ ; actually the case $k=2$ states precisely that $a$ and $b$ commute.

On the other hand, $b^{nm}=b^{mn}$ is always true (because $b$ commutes with itself, in a way).

Comment: How do we prove $ab = ba \implies (ab)^k = a^kb^k?$

Comment: By simple induction on $k$. The first non-trivial case in the induction is $k=2$ and in this case it's exactly a rephrasing of the fact that $ab=ba$.